# Change Xlib window background color with C++

Tags: colors, background, window, x11, xlib

This is Linux. I have created a window and I want to change its background color to green. This is how my code looks like:

```
Window xwin = XCreateSimpleWindow(dis, 
                                  DefaultRootWindow(dis), 
                                  0, 0, 
                                  500, 300, 
                                  0,
                                  WhitePixel(dis, 0),
                                  WhitePixel(dis, 0));
GC gc = XCreateGC(dis, xwin, 0, NULL);
XColor color;
Colormap colormap;
char green[] = "#00FF00";

colormap = DefaultColormap(dis, 0);
XParseColor(dis, colormap, green, &color);
XAllocColor(dis, colormap, &color);

XSetBackground(dis, gc, color.pixel);

XMapWindow(dis, xwin);
XFlush(dis);
```

The window that I see is white. Is it possible to change window background color in Linux, using X11? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want a green background, the last argument of XCreateSimpleWindow is the background colour so ...

```
  XColor color;
  Colormap colormap;
  char green[] = "#00FF00";

  colormap = DefaultColormap(dis, 0);
  XParseColor(dis, colormap, green, &color);
  XAllocColor(dis, colormap, &color);


  Window xwin = XCreateSimpleWindow(dis, 
                   DefaultRootWindow(dis), 
                   0, 0, 
                   500, 300, 
                   0,
                   WhitePixel(dis, 0),
                   color.pixel);

XMapWindow(dis, xwin);
XFlush(dis);
```

Comment: This post is old, but I m willing to say OP asked something different; your answer tells nothing about the possibility of changing background color "after" initial setup, which is something that may be really useful. It would be great if you could elaborate more on that aspect ..