# Change background color of x11 window in C xlib after window is created?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

Almost this very same question has been asked here:
[Change Xlib window background color with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176499/change-xlib-window-background-color-with-c)
But in that anwser it only tells how to set the bg color in the initial setup. I would want to change the bg color after that. (The same way the comment in that anwser puts it).

Here is my code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>   
#define NIL (0)       

void graphic(int color1, int color2){
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NIL); 
    Window w = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), 0, 0, 500, 500, 0, color1, color2); 

    XMapWindow(dpy, w);
    XClearWindow(dpy, w);

    GC gc = XCreateGC(dpy, w, 0, NIL);
    XFlush(dpy);

}

int main(){
    graphic(100,100);
    sleep(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [XChangeWindowAttributes](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/XChangeWindowAttributes.3.xhtml). This is described in [chapter 3. Window Functions](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Window_Functions) in the XLib reference.

And if you intend to do X11 programming on this level, you should plan to have that manual as bedtime reading for the next few months. :)